# Custom init UIViewController query

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am hoping you can help me understand why the below code segment works and the other does not. I am wanting to create a custom initialiser for my UIViewController which has a custom nib file I have created.

My issue is that I want to understand why in the below code the references to newMember and facebookLogin are retained when I hit the viewDidLoad method but in the other segment of code they are not? Can anyone shed some light as to why this would be the case?

**Working Code Block**

```
class RegistrationFormViewController: MiOSBaseViewController
{
    var newMember:Member!
    var facebookLogin: Bool = false

    init(member: Member, facebookLogin: Bool = false) {
        self.newMember = member
        self.facebookLogin = facebookLogin
        super.init(nibName: "RegistrationFormViewController", bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(nibName: "RegistrationFormViewController", bundle: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let view = self.view as! RegistrationFormView
        view.loadViewWith(member: newMember)
        view.customNavBarView.backActionBlock = {
            self.newMember.deleteEntity(MiOSDataContext.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext)
            _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

            return
        }
    }
}
```

**Broken Code Block**

```
class RegistrationFormViewController: MiOSBaseViewController
{
    var newMember:Member!
    var facebookLogin: Bool = false

    init(member: Member, facebookLogin: Bool = false) {
        self.newMember = member
        self.facebookLogin = facebookLogin
        super.init(nibName: "RegistrationFormViewController", bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let view = self.view as! RegistrationFormView
        view.loadViewWith(member: newMember)
        view.customNavBarView.backActionBlock = {
            self.newMember.deleteEntity(MiOSDataContext.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext)
            _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

            return
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Is the `RegistrationFormViewController` subclassed anywhere in your code?

Comment: are you ultimately loading `RegistrationFormViewController` from a storyboard or XIB file (which means you would be using the `init?(coder...` methods)?  If the answer is "yes", how do you ever set `newMember` or `facebookLogin`?

Comment: Hi no it is no @Malik it is not subclassed anywhere. I just dont understand why the properties newMember and FacebookLogin are retained?